# What is the best way to execute an Action Controller with parameters using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ActionController that takes two parameters, both integers.

```
public ActionResult DisplayQuestions(int categoryId, int page) {
...
}
```

When a user pushes right or left, my page directs the user to another page. When the user has reached the end of the pages, i would like to redirect him to a new category, which the action controller can load.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        var currentPage = $("#CurrentPage").val();
        var numberOfPges = $("#NumberOfPages").val();

        if (code == 39) {

            if (currentPage < numberOfPges) {
                // Næste side
                changePage(parseInt(currentPage) + 1);
                $(document).focus();
            }
            else {            
            // Send user to the next category 
            // $("#nextCategory")
            }

        }
        else if (code == 37) {
            // Tilbage
            if ((parseInt(currentPage) - 1) != 0) {
                changePage(parseInt(currentPage) - 1);
                $(document).focus();
            }
            else {
            // Send user to the previous category
            // $("#previousCategory")
            }

        }
    });
```

Basically i would like to call the ActionController with the values of either

```
$("#nextCategory")
or
$("#nextCategory")
```

and page = 1

The JavaScript is in the same ActionController as the View displaying it.

I.E

/Survey2/DisplayQuestions?categoryId=2&page=1

I want to update the whole page. What is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [jQuery submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for this.

in your else statement you'll have something similar to this

```
//Send user to the next category
$.post( "/somepath/someaction", "#nextCategory" );
```